# Why does browser not receive the reponse from custom HTTP server?

Tags: http, rust, rust-tokio

I'm using Tokio to implement a simple HTTP server. The weird thing is the server can receive the request from browser, but the browser can't receive the response from the server.

```ini
# Cargo.toml
[dependencies]
tokio = { version = "1", features = ["full"] }
```

```rust
use tokio::{self, net};
use tokio::io::{AsyncReadExt, AsyncWrite, AsyncWriteExt};
use tokio::net::TcpStream;

async fn process(mut stream: TcpStream) {
    let mut buf = [0u8; 4096];
    loop {
        let n = stream.read(&mut buf).await.unwrap();
        if n == 0 {
            break;
        }
        let s = String::from_utf8_lossy(&buf[0..n]).to_string();
        print!("{}", s);
        if s.ends_with("\r\n\r\n") {
            println!("request received");
            break;
        }
    }

    let response_str = "HTTP/1.1 200 OK
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang=\"en\">
<head>
<meta charset=\"udf-8\">
<title>Hello!</title>
</head>
<body>
HELLO
</body>
</html>
        ";
    println!("response");
    // browser doesn't receive the response that this line of code send.
    stream.write(response_str.as_bytes()).await.unwrap();
    stream.flush().await.unwrap();
    println!("response DONE");
}

#[tokio::main]
async fn main() {
    let listener = net::TcpListener::bind("127.0.0.1:9998").await.unwrap();
    loop {
        let (stream, _) = listener.accept().await.unwrap();
        tokio::spawn(async move{
            process(stream).await;
        });
    }
}
```

Is there any bug in my code?

Comment: It depends on your OS probably, but if your source code file does not use \r\n as line separators, the response string actually contains lines separated just by \n. This is not a valid HTTP response, so the browser may be ignoring it.

Comment: You also have to check how many bytes `write` actually wrote. You probably meant to use `write_all` in it's stead.

Comment: thanks for answering, inspired by the answers, i found that there need a extra line separator between status line and entity body.

Comment: Unrelated to the question, but I believe you meant to write `utf-8` rather than `udf-8`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The HTTP response had a slightly wrong format. There needs to be a extra newline between the status/headers and body. The browser was able to parse the response when written like this:

```
let response_str = "HTTP/1.1 200 OK

<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang=\"en\">
<head>
<meta charset=\"udf-8\">
<title>Hello!</title>
</head>
<body>
HELLO
</body>
</html>"
```

Comment: To be pedantic, the separation between the header and body needs to be `\r\n\r\n` though if your source is encoded with Windows line-endings then this will give the correct result. Better for portability to write the escape characters explicitly though.